# Using boost::associative property map with boost::BIMAP interface

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-bimap

I am not able to implement associative property map interface of boost for a boost bimap.

I have a bimap as follows and I try to define a boost::associative property map for it. I want to use Put and Get helper functions for my bimap.. the code is as follows:

```
 typedef boost::bimaps::bimap< vertex_descriptor_t, size_t >       vd_idx_bimap_t;
 typedef boost::associative_property_map< vd_idx_bimap_t >         asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;

 // define bimap
 vd_idx_bimap_t        my_bimap;
 asso_vd_idx_bimap_t   my_asso_bimap(my_bimap);
```

I get a compile error as

```
  error: no type named âsecond_typeâ in âboost::bimaps::container_adaptor::container_adaptor<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::m.... goes on long list.
```

I am aware, bimaps are supported through property maps. see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/bimap_and_boost/boost_libraries_that_work_well_with_boost_bimap.html#boost_bimap.bimap_and_boost.boost_libraries_that_work_well_with_boost_bimap.boost_property_map) for documentation. Just wondering how would i use associative property map for it.. if i can define left or right bimap for my associative property map, that would also be fine. please suggest.

Comment: Please make your code a SSCCE next time? We're having to guess. I spent more time finding out which headers to include. This is a waste of time and lowers your chances of getting an answer. (I knew the answer right away, but hadn't used Boost Property Map before...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it **which side** of the bimap to use:

```
typedef boost::associative_property_map<vd_idx_bimap_t::left_map> asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;
// OR
typedef boost::associative_property_map<vd_idx_bimap_t::right_map> asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;
```

So, see it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1e7301501fa7f98)**

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp> 
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost; 

int main() 
{
    typedef int vertex_descriptor_t;
    typedef boost::bimaps::bimap< vertex_descriptor_t, size_t > vd_idx_bimap_t;
    typedef boost::associative_property_map<vd_idx_bimap_t::left_map>   asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;

    // define bimap
    vd_idx_bimap_t        my_bimap;
    asso_vd_idx_bimap_t   my_asso_bimap(my_bimap.left);
}
```