# Insert into boost::BIMAP using BOOST::associative property map ... failed

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, boost-bimap

With reference to my previously asked question about boost::bimaps and boost associative property maps interface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654594/using-boostassociative-property-map-with-boostbimap-interface/21660622#21660622), I want to use Put and  Get helper functions for my bimap.

With reference to a sample code given [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1e7301501fa7f98), I tried to add the following and i get a long compile error for assertion failed ... Here is the code :

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp> 
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp> 
#include <boost/bimap/property_map/set_support.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost; 

int main() 
{
  typedef int vertex_descriptor_t;
  typedef boost::bimaps::bimap< vertex_descriptor_t, size_t > vd_idx_bimap_t;
  typedef boost::associative_property_map<vd_idx_bimap_t::left_map>   asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;

  // define bimap
  vd_idx_bimap_t        my_bimap;
  asso_vd_idx_bimap_t   my_asso_bimap(my_bimap.left);

  typedef typename vd_idx_bimap_t::value_type value_type;    
  my_bimap.insert( value_type( 1, 100 ) );
  // print bimap
  for(auto t = my_bimap.left.begin(); t != my_bimap.left.end(); ++t)
      std::cout << t->first << " " << t->second <<  "\n";

  int z = 1;
  std::cout << "value = " << get ( my_bimap.left, z ) << std::endl;    // prints correctly value = 100


  // ERROR here . 
  boost::put( my_asso_bimap, 2, 19 );

 }
```

It gives error as: ( a long list. but i have just put a snippet )

```
  cannot convert âboost::bimaps::detail::non_mutable_data_unique_map_view_access<Derived, Tag, BimapType>::operator[](const CompatibleKey&)::BIMAP_STATIC_ERROR__OPERATOR_BRACKET_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED360::assert_arg<long unsigned int>()â (type âmpl_::failed************ (boost::bimaps::detai
```

There is also one error which gives me error at line number 364 of the file (property_map.hpp) in boost

```
  put(const put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>& pa, K k, const V& v)
 {
   static_cast<const PropertyMap&>(pa)[k] = v;
  }
```

I understand the error that associative map cannot mutate the data as it references to the left map view . but How do I use put and get helper functions ?

I can use GET (my_bimap.left, z ) functions, but I am not able to use PUT function. I wanted to use associative property map for get and put functions to operate on actual bimap so that i dont have to use insert( value_type() )...

I hope I am clear enough for my problem. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot update bimap entries via iterators:

> The relations stored in the Bimap will not be in most cases modifiable directly by iterators because both sides are used as keys of key-based sets. When a bimap left view iterator is dereferenced the return type is signature-compatible with a std::pair< const A, const B >.

So there's your answer. Likewise, you couldn't

```
my_bimap.left[2] = 19;
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/differences_with_standard_maps.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.differences_with_standard_maps.iterator__value_type

Now, reading a bit more on there leads me to "suspect" the following solution:

```
typedef bm::bimap< vertex_descriptor_t, bm::list_of<size_t> > vd_idx_bimap_t;
```

Disclaimer: I don't know about the semantics that this changes (?) but it at least appears to support writable references. The below sample prints

```
1 100
value = 100
1 100
2 42
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/780ceb1fd0e9ed90)**

---

#### Full Listing

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp> 
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp> 
#include <boost/bimap/property_map/set_support.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/list_of.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost; 

int main() 
{
    typedef int vertex_descriptor_t;
    namespace bm = boost::bimaps;
    typedef bm::bimap< vertex_descriptor_t, bm::list_of<size_t> > vd_idx_bimap_t;
    typedef boost::associative_property_map<vd_idx_bimap_t::left_map>   asso_vd_idx_bimap_t;

    // define bimap
    vd_idx_bimap_t        my_bimap;
    asso_vd_idx_bimap_t   my_asso_bimap(my_bimap.left);

    typedef typename vd_idx_bimap_t::value_type value_type;    
    my_bimap.insert( value_type( 1, 100 ) );

    // print bimap
    for(auto t = my_bimap.left.begin(); t != my_bimap.left.end(); ++t)
        std::cout << t->first << " " << t->second <<  "\n";

    int z = 1;
    std::cout << "value = " << get ( my_bimap.left, z ) << std::endl;    // prints correctly value = 100

    boost::put( my_asso_bimap, 2, 42 );

    for(auto t = my_bimap.left.begin(); t != my_bimap.left.end(); ++t)
        std::cout << t->first << " " << t->second <<  "\n";
 }
```

Comment: @sehe...thanks. this worked. but I am sorry I should have told you more about my intentions behind using bimaps. Just using plain maps and associative maps will work for general sense. The thing is: I want to create a bimap which key and value..Initially the bimap is filled with left view map (using associative prop map for it). And later on, I want to use right view through another associative property map (say right_asso_bimap ). In my case, I am sure that both the key and value are unique so bimap is most suitable.