# number of vertex in every component- boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, boost

im kind of new with boost library (windows 7\ visual studio 2010). I followed this example code:

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>


using namespace std;

int main(int , char* []) 
{
  using namespace boost;
  {
    typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> Graph;

    Graph G;
    add_edge(0, 1, G);
    add_edge(1, 4, G);
    add_edge(4, 0, G);
    add_edge(2, 5, G);
    
    std::vector<int> component(num_vertices(G));

    int num = connected_components(G, &component[0]);
    
    std::vector<int>::size_type i;
    cout << "Total number of components: " << num << endl;
    for (i = 0; i != component.size(); ++i)
      cout << "Vertex " << i <<" is in component " << component[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the code builds the graph and prints which vertex belongs to which component by the for loop.

is there an example of function that gets a graph and returns\ stores which vertex belongs to which component- in organized way(some kind of data structure)? and not with for loop?

I tried to search [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html), hope I didn't miss it.

thanks.

**EDIT:**
the goal is to take measurements on every component (such as number of nodes, diameter, number of neighbors for every node in one component..)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an associative property map:

```
std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, Graph::vertices_size_type> map;

auto const num = connected_components(G, make_assoc_property_map(map));
std::cout << "Total number of components: " << num << std::endl;

for (auto& e : map)
    std::cout << "Vertex " << e.first << " is in component " << e.second << std::endl;
```

Of course, now the mystery is, how do you effectively get the reverse map?

---

<sup>*(meanwhile, life happens...)*</sup>

---

**Sorry** ran out of steam writing this. Here's a link to an earlier write up that hopefully serves as inspiration to get the bidirectional associative *writable* property map (in the context of another BGL call, but you can hopefully imagine the connection).

- [Cut set of a graph, Boost Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697477/cut-set-of-a-graph-boost-graph-library/26699982#26699982)

Slightly related samples:

- [Using boost::associative property map with boost::BIMAP interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654594/using-boostassociative-property-map-with-boostbimap-interface/21660622?s=1|3.8857#21660622)
- [Insert into boost::BIMAP using BOOST::associative property map ... failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666282/insert-into-boostbimap-using-boostassociative-property-map-failed/21666858?s=2|3.7632#21666858)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, the main issue is to take every component (component- connected sub graph) as input to function that returns number of nodes\ diameter\ number of neighbors for every node in one component etc... so i guess that component (connected sub graph) is supposed to be in some kind of BGL data structure (as input to other BGL function)?

Comment: I think you'll have to arragne for this data structure. The algorithm doesn't assume you wish to incur the "extra" cost. I suppose you could write a property map adaptor that directly writes the components into proper subgraphs, but I'd not optimize that far unless I were absolutely sure I needed it. And in that case I might consider optimizing the actual `connected_component` algorithm (adapting _it_ to your needs) to keep things simpler